# pytest-cov options for code coverage from external libraries

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest-cov

Currently I'm trying to implement an automation testing tool for python projects. Is it possible to collect the code coverage from external libraries using pytest-cov module? As far as I know only the `coverage` module will report the code coverage from external libraries!

Example:

```
import random


def test_rand():
  assert random.randint(0,10) == 5
```

Using the command `coverage run -m --pylib pytest file.py::test_rand` we can get the code coverage from external libraries (e.g. random module in our case).

Is it possible to do the same thing using pytest-cov instead?

Answer (score 0):

By default pytest-cov will report coverage for all libraries, including external.

If you run `pytest --cov` against your code it will produce many lines of coverage including `py`, `pytest`, `importlib`, etc.

To limit the scope of the coverage, i.e. you only want to inspect coverage for random, just pass the module names to the cov option e.g. `pytest --cov=random`. The coverage report then only considers the named modules. You can also  pass multiple modules by specifying multiple `cov` values, e.g. `pytest --cov=random --cov=pytest`

Here's an example running your test to produce coverage only against `random`

```
$ pytest --cov=random
====== test session starts ======
platform linux -- Python 3.6.12, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
plugins: cov-2.12.1
collected 1 item

test_something.py F
[100%]

=========== FAILURES ============
___________ test_rand ___________

    def test_rand():
      import random
    
>     assert random.randint(0,10) == 5
E     AssertionError: assert 0 == 5
E      +  where 0 = <bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at ...>>(0, 10)

test_something.py:6: AssertionError

---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.6.12-final-0 -----------
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover
/.../random.py     350    334     --
TOTAL              350    334     5%
```